# Rails Gem Issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed Rails 3.2.1 with Ruby 1.9.3p0

```
davesahil@sahil-pc:~$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.1)
```

`$rails --version` gives me this

```
/home/davesahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails ([">= 0"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/davesahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Its been a while since I last worked on rails. Am I missing something over here?

Comment: Have you installed bundler? `gem install bundler`. `rails new myproject` `bundle install`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem with rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.8.7.
The following worked for me :

```
sudo gem install railties
```

Comment: Hey thanks a ton. That worked flawlessly. I had railties installed already, but I re-installed it and now rails is working.

Comment: It was working yesterday. Today it wasn't working any more. This worked all good, thanks!